# c# Binary Reader System.InvalidCastException:

Tags: c#, winforms

The error I am getting is.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'project.Book[]' to type 'project.Book'.'

As it currently stands i have no errors saving the file yet when i try and open the file and display it in my WinForms application i am met with this error, i have checked other posts for this problem with saving data into an object and then into a single dimensional array but can't find any specifics relating to this problem.

Here is my class Book

```
    [Serializable]
    class Book
    {
        private string author;
        private string title;
        private string publisher;
        private double price;
        private string date;
        private int ISBN;

        //vehcicle constructor
        public Book()
        { }
        //overloaded constructor
        public Book(int bookISBN, string bookAuthor, string bookTitle, string bookPublisher, double bookPrice, string bookDate)
        {
            ISBN = bookISBN;
            author = bookAuthor;
            title = bookTitle;
            publisher = bookPublisher;
            price = bookPrice;
            date = bookDate;
        }
        public int gsISBN
        {
            get { return ISBN; }
            set { ISBN = value; }
        }
        public string gsAuthor//author getter and setter
        {
            get { return author; }
            set { author = value; }
        }
        public string gsTitle//title getter and setter
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }
        public string gsPublisher//publisher getter and setter
        {
            get { return publisher; }
            set { publisher = value; }
        }
        public double gsPrice//price getter and setter
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }
        public string gsDate//date getter and setter
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }
        }
        public string Printbook()//Printbook string for the base constructor
        {
            return gsISBN + " - " + gsAuthor + ", " + gsTitle;

        }
    }
```

And here is my binaryWrite / read.

```
private void SaveBinaryBook()
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Book.dat", FileMode.Create);

            // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            try
            {
                //myBooks is the array 
                formatter.Serialize(fs, myBooks);

            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

```
  private void LoadBinaryBook()
        {


            // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Book.dat", FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
                // assign the reference to the local variable.
                Book book = (Book)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                currentIndexBook++;
                DisplayBook();
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am new to this and this is all for an assignment so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in `LoadBinaryBook`:

```c#
Book book = (Book)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

The `Deserialize` method is returning an array of the `Book` (so `Book[]`) object, but you're trying to cast it to a single `Book`. Because in `SaveBinaryBook`:

```c#
//myBooks is the array 
formatter.Serialize(fs, myBooks);
```

In `LoadBinaryBook` you'll want to deserialize as an array as well:

```c#
Book[] books = (Book[])formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```